How to access Objective-C @property with name instead of self.name?
TL;DR What was the correct way to access an Objective-C @property (...) foo as foo instead of self.foo?
Details:
One of my iOS projects still uses some Objective-C code I have written several years ago.
// SomeObject.h
@interface SomeObject : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *foo;
@end

// SomeObject.m
@implementation SomeObject { ... }
@synthesize foo;

- (void)someMethod {
   foo = @"bar";
}

- (void)otherMethod {
   NSLog(@"Foo: %@", foo);  // ---> "bar"
}
@end

This works fine as intended. Now I would like to use a getter to access some new Swift code instead of setting foo manually:
// SomeObject.m
@implementation SomeObject { ... }
@synthesize foo;

- (NSString *)foo {
   return [SwiftObject getFoo];
}

- (void)otherMethod {
   NSLog(@"Foo: %@", foo);  // ---> nil
   NSLog(@"Foo: %@", self.foo);  // ---> "swiftBar"
}
@end

So, using the getter only works correct when using self.foo instead of just foo. This is not a big problem but it would require to replaces all usage of foo with self.foo in the existing code.
Is there a clean way to avoid this, use the foo getter and still use foo instead of self.foo?

When you access foo you are accessing the ivar directly. When you use [self foo] or self.foo you access the property via the getter.  This is why it is a bad idea to use foo instead of self.foo in Objective-C unless you specifically need to bypass the getter.  TLDR: change foo to self.foo in your objective c code.

That's why Apple recommend to use properties in Objective-C and doesn't allow use ivars in Swift

You can use marcos but it's to dirty, better to use find+replace


TL;DR What was the correct was to access a Objective-C @property (...) foo as foo instead of self.foo?

It's not possible to access an Objective-C property using a bare name, without a target (i.e., without self.) — this is because @property is a shorthand for generating getter + setter methods on a type, and method calls always require an object to be called on.
Instead, your first snippet of code works for an unrelated reason:

By default, declaring a bare @property without a corresponding @synthesize directive will generate an instance variable for you to store the actual value in the property. In the case of a property like foo, the default generated ivar will be _foo
However, you can provide your own name for the variable with an explicit @synthesize directive, and when you do that, you can access the ivar with any name that you want:

Leaving out the @synthesize directive is equivalent to @synthesize foo=_foo; (i.e., map the foo property to a _foo ivar)
@synthesize foo; on its own is equivalent to @synthesize foo=foo; (i.e., map the foo property to a foo ivar)
@synthesize foo=bar; maps the foo property to a bar ivar



It happens to be that in Objective-C classes, ivars are accessed by their bare name directly — in the case of your SomeObject class, writing foo refers to the ivar itself, not to the property.

In your original code, because the foo property is actually using the foo ivar (because you're not implementing the foo method yourself), foo and self.foo happen to return the same value
In your updated code, you explicitly synthesize a foo ivar with the @synthesize directive, but then provide your own implementation for the foo getter, which is what's called when you write self.foo. Because the foo ivar is never set, it gets a nil value by default

In other words, you can't avoid writing self.foo when referring to properties, and in general, it's recommended you avoid @synthesize foo; in order to avoid possible mixups when accessing the method vs. the ivar directly.

I'll add that the direct reference to the ivar foo is equivalent to self->foo which is of course quite different from self.foo.
